# CSS select bootstrap table row which has certain class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, class, row

This is part of my bootstrap table:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <div><span class="approve"></span></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I want to change the background-color of the whole row when it contains span with class .approve

This is what I tried:

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(2n+1):has(span):has(.approve) > td {
   background-color: #fff3c0;
}
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(2n):has(span):has(.approve) > td {
   background-color: #fff8d9;
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. I also tried to remove .table-striped and use this CSS:

```
.table > tbody > tr:has(span):has(.approve) > td {
   background-color: #fff8d9;
}
```

It doesnt work either. Is my CSS wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with:

```
table tbody tr:has(span.approve) {
  background-color: #fff8d9;
}
```

or

```
table tbody tr:has(span.approve) td {
  background-color: #fff8d9;
}
```

if you want to add background color to `td` elements instead of `tr`.

Worth noticing is that `:has()` pseudo-element is quite new and it is not fully supported by all browsers yet (for example it is not supported by Firefox).

Comment: Thank You!! This was it. And since I feel like I'm the last single user of Firefox it propably doesn't really matter for my project :)